# Build a trail cart

Tags: outdoor, pull

I want to build a cart for carrying camping equipment and supplies as a potential alternative to a backpack. Pulling a cart with the backpack in it *should* be easier than carrying it on my back, at least for a flat and even surface. Whether the trails I will be traveling are flat and even enough I don't yet know. The cart would need to support a weight of 25 lbs. and be roughly 18" wide by 30" high. I'd attach a strap to it and wrap the strap around my waist.  I would attach the pack to the cart with string or a bungee cord.

I was going to build the cart out of schedule 80 PVC pipe and then attach wheels to it, for example https://wheeleez.com/product/wz1-wak-38tt/ (these are bigger and heavier than I want, this is just for illustration).  This might be better:  https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200660524_200660524. Bigger wheels will roll better and will surmount rocks more easily; the tradeoff is the extra weight.

Two questions:

- What would be an ideal PVC pipe diameter?
- What would be an ideal wheel diameter and material?

Comment: Unless you plan to only use this one or two times, in mild weather and in placid terrain, PVC is a poor choice.  It has too much flex, a poor strength to weight ratio, and susceptibility to temperatures, UV, and fatigue failure.  Use steel allows or aluminum alloys, the former is easier for novices to fab with.   20" wheels should suffice.  If a ready made hiking cart is not to your taste, you might consider using or modifying a (jogging) baby stroller.

Comment: Along the lines of @Brock Adams suggestion a bicycle trailer used for towing children are light weight and robust. They are also readily available  on the used market as children quickly out grow them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I did not know that about PVC, thank you.  I modified a bicycle trailer for hauling groceries, but it's not suitable for trails because it is too wide.

Comment: See this : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/15931/10902

Comment: *Personally* I prefer the sort of paths where wheels are not an advantage, but YMMV.

Comment: Unless you have back issues that would prevent using a backpack, I see limited value in using a cart that will likely weigh at least half as much as your intended load. It might be worthwhile for some, but I'd imagine most people would prefer to carry a 25lb backpack than pull a 35-40lb cart over rough terrain.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask on Outdoors whether this is a good idea.

Comment: @Reid: done: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/pulling-vs-carrying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at a standard, two-wheel, LARGE (bicycle sized) wheel garden cart, or possibly a wheelbarrow form, again with a LARGE, bicycle, wheel.) Bicycle wheels are a common, well developed, strong, lightweight wheel with many options for tires and sizes.

The single-wheel advantage becomes blatantly obvious the first time you hit a side-hill and your multi-wheel cart decides to roll over sideways. A wheelbarrow with one wheel is only sensitive to side-hill when you set it down on its two legs. I would NOT suggest using a standard wheelbarrow as seen today.

[image: Basic wooden wheelbarrow frame]

This is an illustration of a wood-framed (and probably wheeled, but swap that for a bicycle wheel) "bare-bones" form from this translated article (I was just looking for a good, basic, not too modern wheelbarrow illustration. I haven't read the article in any detail):

https://spot.colorado.edu/~richtea/prints.html

How much load you have to lift at the handles varies as you move the load more over the wheel, while how stable it is varies with how low you can get it. If you can arrange your "pack" as two "panniers" you can get it right over the wheel while keeping it low, by having it to the sides of the wheel. You still have to push or pull the weight, but you don't have to lift it. Still, on many of my local trails, you'd likely come to regret having to get it over rocks & trees (even with a large wheel) but your local trails may be more developed or involve fewer stair-stepped steep sections. It could also skid sideways on wet rock.

You could pick up a pre-owned bicycle for not much or free and adapt from there. You might want to retain the brake for downhills.

Comment: My first thought is that such a design would tip over too easily, but perhaps not. Perhaps attaching each pole to each hip would be sufficient. (nods head)

Comment: Given your load is proposed to be ~25 lbs, I doubt it would be a major issue. I work with some folks who like "two-wheel" wheelbarrows, and those are FAR more prone to tipping over on any side slope, which is why I prefer the single-wheel version. Where flat enough, the garden-cart setup is good as it distributes the load over the axle, but where not flat enough, that's either a rollover or having to take tiny loads to not roll over.

Comment: Apparently there is such a thing, for example https://www.competitivecyclist.com/weehoo-igo-cargo-bike-trailer?skidn=WEH000C-ONECOL-ONESIZ&ti=U2VhcmNoIFJlc3VsdHM6aUdvIENhcmdvIEJpa2UgVHJhaWxlOjE6MTppR28gQ2FyZ28gQmlrZSBUcmFpbGU= or https://www.quietkat.com/product/2019-quietkat-cargo-trailer/

Answer (score 1):

Its 2023 and a lot of engineering has addressed some of the issues. First, pulling a one wheel cart is less efficient - despite the publics concepts, PUSHING it works better, it's more easily controlled, and you can steer it to avoid irregularities. There are quite a few models now available both here and in the US.

The more vertical the frame the less the individual has to support - the old "wheelbarrow" style with front wheel leading means the load is half way back.Put the load OVER the wheel and it's no longer an issue. Tall tires make it more tippy than a lower one but the diameter does have an effect, a larger rolling radius negotiates terrain more easily.

Overall weight of the framing can be controlled, using square metal tubing wheel barrow handles may be one option, or square sign posts is another. Both have a lot of bending resistance. If terrain is considered rougher - across a forest floor - some have resorted to a "walking beam" design with wheels at either end, pivoting in the middle, which allows it to lift up and over smaller rocks and limbs. It can also be turned around and pulled over more easily. There are a lot of alternative designs out there now, when you include monowalkers, hiking carts, game carts, etc in your search terms. One concern is use in wilderness areas - "no wheels!" is a mantra with fans yet there is NO SPECIFIC LANGUAGE to that effect. It's simply a popular notion spread by the uninformed - and doesn't apply if you have a certified disability. "45 pound weight limit, no repetitive twisting or bending" might be one Im familiar with.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/167671)